# md-select performance issues (too many watchers)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have an array with more than 200 objects that I'm displaying using `md-select`:

```html
<md-input-container>
   <md-select ng-model="selectedCountry" placeholder="Select country">
      <md-option ng-value="country.code" ng-repeat="country in countries">{{ ::country.name }}</md-option>
   </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

[(Codepen)](http://codepen.io/Boxiom/pen/JXomQO)

I'm using [ng-stats](https://github.com/kentcdodds/ng-stats) to keep track of how many watchers I have on my pages, and noticed that the `md-select`-directive creates over *500* watchers in this case. In comparison, the regular `select` element with `ng-options` only creates 2-3.

I wasn't able to find any issues related to this on GitHub, so I'm wondering if I'm using the directive in a wrong way? Is there anything I can do to reduce the number of watchers? My app is going to have at least a couple of more select-lists like this, and I don't want to end up with thousands of watchers and horrible performance (especially since the recommended max limit is 2000?).

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same, did you find anything? or the only workaround is to not use the `md-select`?

Comment: Yeah, one-time binding on `ng-value` solved it for me! Like this: `ng-value=::country.code"`.